# How to merge WYSIWYG fields from separate nodes

Tags: nodes, database, wysiwyg

I would like to know if it is possible to merge the contents of two separate WYSIWYG fields from separate nodes to create a new node containg both.

Does anybody know of a module that performs this function or something similar, or would this require the writing of a new module?

The use case is for a newsletter, the WYSIWYG fields being populated by articles, and saved to separate nodes. The end result would be a node that contained all articles in a single WYSIWYG field.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Drupal Answers. You can use [views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module with [simplenews](http://drupal.org/project/simplenews) to achieve above functionality.

Please find simplenews features below.

- Sending nodes as newsletters to subscribers
- Multiple newsletter categories with separate settings
- Per category and multi-signup Blocks and Pages
- Subscriber management including mass-subscription and export
- Optional E-mail confirmations for anonymous users
- Customizable newsletter templates
- Support for HTML (including text alternative) newsletter when used in combination with a supported mail system module
- **Views and Rules integration**
- Support for multi-language newsletters

Comment: Hey mate,Thanks for your anwser. I had not considered simplenews. I'm really looking for another solution but this might help me get a further step along the way. I want to send the mail from civicrm, in order to track opens and click throughs. Simplenews may help me create the newsletter, which I can then copy and paste into the civi mail builder.